# Реализация условного запроса к БД

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Добрый день сообщество. Прошу помощи в следующем:

На сайте реализовано переключение вкладок на JS. При нажатии на каждую вкладку на экран выводится результат запроса к БД.  Собственно код:

```html
$resultat1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE категория='cat1'",$connection);
```

Тобишь каждый таб показывает выборку лишь по одной, соответствующей ей, категории

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs_menu a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.tabs_menu .active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   var tab = $(this).attr('href');
   $('.tab').not(tab).css({
    'display': 'none'
   });
   $(tab).fadeIn(400);
  });
 });
```

Также реализован поиск, который делает запрос к БД и выводит материалы по всем категориям.
Можно ли реализовать поиск с учетом отслеживания активного в данный момент таба? Условно говоря, если выбрана третья категория (таб), то и поиск будет идти лишь по третьей. Понимаю что следует сделать невидимый input type="radio" для каждого таба, и в запросе к бд проверять его, но как это реализовать я представления не имею.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: точно так же как и табы реализованы.

Comment: смотрите в сторону Ajax. единстевнное над чем надо подумать, как при Вашем функционале передать те или иные параметры в запрос

Comment: лучше все таки один input типа hidden на всю страницу и в блоке переключения вкладки меняете в нем значение с помощью JS. `form.inp.value=X`

Comment: @Mike Я правильно понял что следует добавить саму форму в панель переключения, 1 input с visibility:hidden и каждую ссылку поместить в отдельный <option> select'a с соотвествующим value?

Comment: ну я бы делал одну форму на всю страницу или не делал бы формы вообще, а использовал ajax. на счет "ссылок" не представляю что вы имеете ввиду, в вопросе об этом ни слова. Ваша задача при вызове поиска передать еще один параметр говорящий о том какая вкладка открыта, а как конкретно это делать зависит исключительно от того как этот самый поиск вызываете

Answer (score 0):

В коментариях [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) дал отличный совет.

Создайте скрытое поле: `<input type="hidden" id="categoryType" name="categoryType">`, и при переходе на новый таб меняйте в нем значение, для этого нужно добавить одну строку в ваш js:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs_menu a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.tabs_menu .active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   var tab = $(this).attr('href');

                        $('#categoryType").val(tab); // Добавленная строка

   $('.tab').not(tab).css({
    'display': 'none'
   });
   $(tab).fadeIn(400);
  });
 });
```

И тогда у вас на сервере будет доступна информация о активном табе, `$_REQUEST['categoryType']`. Этот вариант подходит если у вас поиск работает без Ajax. В случае с Ajax все намного проще.

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   data: {
       ...
       categoryType: $('.active').attr('href'),
       ...
   },
   ...
});
```

И на сервера информация о активном табе будет лежать там же где и в первом случае `$_REQUEST['categoryType']`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Разобрался